# In mobile, hide input and avoid it getting submitted

Tags: html, css, mobile

Good morning,

I have a form where i need to input a field through a select.
To simplify the user selection i used an input and a datalist, to work as a selectpicker, but that runs smoother and faster.

Since the javascript in mobile is not working, i decided to create a normal select, which, by using CSS media rules, is displayed only on mobile, while the previous datalist is displayed only on bigger screens.

Problem is: since i need the data coming from one of those input, both have the attribute required. But hiding it with display: none obviously doesn't "delete" the required.

At the end of the day, i'm asking if there is a way to "delete" the required attribute only in mobile, preferably via CSS.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label for="anagrafica"> Cliente :</label>

        <!--visualizzabile sono in pc (non funziona su mobile)-->
        <div class="onlyOnPC">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="anagrafica" list="anagrafica" required/>
            <datalist id="anagrafica">
            //list of options
            </datalist>
        </div>


        <div class="onlyOnMobile">
          <select name="anagrafica" id="anagrafica" class="form-control" required>
              <option value=""></option>
              //list of options
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {  
    .onlyOnPC{
        display: none;
    }
    .onlyOnMobile{
        display: block;
    }
}@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {  
    .onlyOnPC{
        display: block;
    }
    .onlyOnMobile{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: try using bootstrap inbuilt classes `visible-*` and `hidden-*`. * is screen media classes like  xs,sm,md and lg.

Comment: Thanks, but i wanted to be more specific than bootstrap xs-sm ecc..
I haven't tried though, so i don't know if it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into this

```
  var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
  if(width < 768) {
     $("input").attr("required", "false");
  } else {
     $("input").attr("required", "true");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try and let you know.

Comment: @StackAle okay sure

Comment: I played around with it, it seems to be working fine, thanks